# How to conditionally format a table from Excel in the layout view?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, layouts

I'm making a layout view, thing and have run into a problem. I have formatted my table beautifully in Excel, see Picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osevV.png), but when I import it to QGIS it clears the formatting. The color goes away, and more annoyingly my percentages become 10 point decimals, oh no, Picture [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXTei.png)!
How can I implement the table like you see in the first in the print layout element. I know I could just insert the picture of the Excel document, but I want to know how to do this in theory with a attribute table made in QGIS.

[image: The Beautifully formatted table in Excel]
[image: Nasty table]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 5):

To define a conditional formatting, open the layer's attribute table in the main window of QGIS (not in the print composer). When the attribute table is open, you find a symbol on the top to open the panel for conditional formatting where you can select the field you want to format and than add a new rule. Than you can define a condition or use again the expression editor. In the example in the screenshot below, I defined that every cell that contains a number that ends in a digit equal 5 or higher is formatted with red background - just to get a random pattern for demonstration purpose. The expression looks like that:  `right("Pop_tot" ,1) >=5`

[image]

Again, documentation here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=attribute%20table%20conditional%20formatting#formatting-of-table-cells-using-conditions

When you defined your attribute table accordingly, you can go back to the print composer and just select again the inserted attribut table and go to element properties - appearance (as in the first answer, see above). Than simply click the checkbox to apply conditional layerstyling as you can see in this screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Select the attribute tabe you insertet in your print layout, than go to the element properties and select appearance. Than select advanced customisation. In the opening dialogue, you have several options to format even and odd rows or colums, the first and last column or row as well as the header. See my screenshot - it's in german, but it should be clear.

[image]

Otherwise, see the documentation here:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_attribute_table.html?highlight=attribute%20table%20item#appearance

To format your numbers accordingly, go again to element properties and select this time to top entry "Main properties". Select attributes and in the opening dialogue go to the number whose format you want to change. Select the symbol ɛ​ to open the expression editor and define an expression - see my screenshot, I selected format_number expression to format the number to 2 digits:

[image]

Again, see the official documentation here:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_attribute_table.html?highlight=attribute%20table%20item#main-properties

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful to me, however I still have one question. I only see options to do every other cell, is there an option to format it such that positive values in one column are one color, and negative values are another color, like in excel?